# strings and characters in Golang

Tags: string, go, unicode

I need a little help understanding how strings are managed in go.

consider the following go code...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {

    var1, var2 := 'a', 'ă'

    fmt.Printf("For var1 - Char: %c, Type: %T, Value: %d\n", var1, var1, var1)
    fmt.Printf("For var2 - Char: %c, Type: %T, Value: %d\nSo far so good, rune is an alias for int32 and the value is the Unicode Decimal Value\n\n", var2, var2, var2)

    str := "aă"

    fmt.Printf("%v is %v bytes \nI understand this, the a takes up one byte the ă takes up two bytes\n\n", str, len(str))

    for i := 0; i < len(str); {
        r, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(str[i:])
        fmt.Printf("For character #%v in \"str\" (%q) Char: %c, Type: %T, Value: %d\n", i+1, str, r, r, r)
        i += size
    }
    fmt.Printf("Same as above, done differently - the loop loops through the characters in the \nstring \"str\" by determining how much to jump in the underlying slice for the string\n")
    fmt.Printf("the first iteration only goes over one position and then the next iteration \ngoes over two\n")

    fmt.Println("\nNow lets go Byte by Byte ...")
    fmt.Println("Byte (not rune) at position 0: ", str[0])
    fmt.Println("Byte (not rune) at position 1: ", str[1])
    fmt.Println("Byte (not rune) at position 2: ", str[2])
    fmt.Println("Ok, I am a little confused. Position 0 holds the unicode decimal value of \"a\"")
    fmt.Printf("but what is %v and %v to  \"ă\" ?\n", str[1], str[2])

}
```

that puts out the following

> For var1 - Char: a, Type: int32, Value: 97
>
> For var2 - Char: ă, Type: int32, Value: 259
>
> So far so good, rune is an alias for int32 and the value is the
> Unicode Decimal Value aă is 3 bytes  I understand this, the a takes up
> one byte the ă takes up two bytes   For character #1 in "str" ("aă")
> Char: a, Type: int32, Value: 97
>
> For character #2 in "str" ("aă") Char: ă, Type: int32, Value: 259
>
> Same as above, done differently - the loop loops through the
> characters in the string "str" by determining how much to jump in the
> underlying slice for the string the first iteration only goes over one
> position and then the next iteration  goes over two   Now lets go Byte
> by Byte ...
>
> Byte (not rune) at position 0:  97
>
> Byte (not rune) at position 1:  196
>
> Byte (not rune) at position 2:  131
>
> Ok, I am a little confused. Position 0 holds the unicode decimal value
> of "a" but what is 196 and 131 to  "ă" ?

Comment: The string is utf8 encoded, which is why you used the `"unicode/utf8"` package. What do you expect `str[1]` and `str[2]` to be?

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the UTF-8 encoding here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

196: 110 00100

131: 10 000011

So: 00100 000011 -> 259

Comment: Thanks - I just needed a little nudge in the right direction.